# How can i check app installed in react native code

Tags: react-native

i tried to check other app install in my react native project, I'm used module like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-check-app-install
But always got this error:
Cannot read property 'pkgName' of undefined
Here is my code:

```
    AppInstalledChecker
    .isAppInstalledAndroid('com.skype.raider') 
    .then((isInstalled) => {
        // isInstalled is true if the app is installed or false if not 
         console.log('App Skype status: ', isInstalled);
    });
```

Anyone can suggest me one way so check app install in react native (both: iOS/android)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.isAppInstalledAndroid('skype')` instead? Since the `pkgName` is already defined in the app-list object. source: https://github.com/redpandatronicsuk/react-native-check-app-install/blob/master/app-list.js

Comment: I tried react-native-check-app-install and fail because it really buggy :)  At first I decided to fix some bugs but at the end I just installed react-native-shared-group-preferences and forget about react-native-check-app-install :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Google Play considers the list of installed apps to be personal and sensitive user data.

As we are using

```
AppInstalledChecker
    .isAppInstalledAndroid()
```

method for checking app installed check, for that we have to white-list the queries in manifest.xml

Reference : https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.instagram.android"/>
    …
</queries>
```

2. For adding Queries need to upgrade build gradle version:
   new default settings and features for package visibility in Android 11 that need to add  you must update your android gradle plugin version

Reference: [How can I fix "unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969917/how-to-fix-unexpected-element-queries-found-in-manifest-error/64854044#64854044)

I have updated from 3.5.2 to 4.0.2

Now [react-native-check-app-install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-check-app-install) module working as expected

Hope this is resolved!

The link above should now be working (had to add this sentence so I could appease the minimum length of edit limitation)

Comment: It's working as it should after I whitelist the package in manifest.

Answer (score 3):

install this

```
https://github.com/KjellConnelly/react-native-shared-group-preferences
```

and

```
async check() {
    try {
        await SharedGroupPreferences.isAppInstalledAndroid("com.farsitel.bazaar")
        // IF IS INSTALL
    } catch (e) {
        // IF IS NOT INSTALL
    }
}
```

Comment: what about ios ?

Comment: @MuhammadAshfaq for iOS you can use "import { Linking } from 'react-native'" and then Linking.canOpenURL(iOS_URL_scheme), where iOS_URL_scheme you can find in google for each separate application

Answer (score 0):

**Android**

I. For app's which has deep links like '*waze://*', '*mapsme://*' you can use:

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'
...
Linking.canOpenURL('waze://ul?ll=${latitude},${longitude}&navigate=yes')
```

OR

II. You can use for absolutely all apps (for example with deep links like "*https://...*")
https://github.com/KjellConnelly/react-native-shared-group-preferences

**iOS**

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'
...
Linking.canOpenURL(iOS_app_URL_Scheme)
...
```

where *iOS_app_URL_Scheme* you can find via Google for each separate app. Like "waze://", "comgooglemaps://", "osmandmaps://" etc

Answer (score 0):

For expo managed workflow, you can create an Expo plugin that adds the necessary  tag. This is the code in case it helps anyone:

```js
const { withAndroidManifest } = require('@expo/config-plugins');

module.exports = function androidManifestPlugin(config) {
  return withAndroidManifest(config, (config) => {
    let androidManifest = config.modResults.manifest;

    androidManifest.queries.push({
      package: {
        $: {
          'android:name': 'com.whatsapp',
        },
      },
    });

    console.log('androidManifest', androidManifest);
    return config;
  });
};
```

This will add the following tag:

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp"/>
</queries>
```

You can then check the existence of the application by:

```js
const exists = await Linking.canOpenURL('whatsapp://send?text=Hello')
```