# How can I fix "unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>" error?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, manifest

All of a sudden, I am getting this build error in my Android project:

```
unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: yes it is working in case <query. tag in manifest classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")

Current setting:

classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4")

Answer (score 398, accepted):

The Android Gradle Plugin needs to know about new manifest elements, particularly
for the manifest merger process. The plugin has a tendency to get confused if it
sees elements in the manifest merger that it does not recognize, tossing out
build errors like the one in the question.

In this case, Android 11 introduced `<queries>` as a manifest element, and older versions of the Android Gradle Plugin do not know about that element.

The fact that this occurs from manifest merger means that simply upgrading a dependency
might bring about this error. For example, if you upgrade to the latest
version of `com.awesome:awesome-library`, and it contained a `<queries>` element
in its manifest, you might crash with the aforementioned error in your builds,
even without any other changes in your code.

Google released a series of patch versions of the Android Gradle Plugin to address this:

- `3.3.3`
- `3.4.3`
- `3.5.4`
- `3.6.4`
- `4.0.1`

If you are using an existing plugin in the `3.3.*` through `4.0.*` series, upgrade
to the associated patch version (or higher) from that list, and you should no longer
run into that error (e.g., `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'`).

If you are using Android Studio 4.1 or higher, with a matching
Android Gradle Plugin (e.g., in the `4.1.*` series), you should be fine without
any changes. Those plugin versions were already aware of `<queries>`.

See [this Android Developers Blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/preparing-your-build-for-package-visibility-in-android-11.html) for more.

Comment: "Google released a series of patch versions of the Android Gradle Plugin to address this"
Very nice note if you don't want to go through fixing issues related to upgrading the gradle plugin version.

Comment: My build tool version was 3.5.0. I have upgraded to 3.5.4, it solved the issue. Good explanation

Comment: Great! For Unity, edit the file in the path. -> /Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.20f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/GradleTemplates/baseProjectTemplate.gradle

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.2-all.zip
I still get issue how to fix?

Comment: A great explanation.. in my case I got a fix by slightly upgrading gradle version on Android Studio v3.5.2
from: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1' 
to: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'

Comment: Oh god! This so clears things up for me. I've been wandering around for a week now trying to figure out wth is wrong with that queries tag!! I'm getting this error in Unity. I'm gonna upgrade to the latest version that uses a newer version of Gradle and see if it fixes it. Thanks so much man! God bless you!

Comment: Unfortunately I am experiencing this problem even when using seemingly patched gradle 3.4.3. Problem started occuring after updating play-services-ads to 20.3.0.

Comment: Updating Gradle Plugin to 3.5.4 fixed the problem.

Comment: you can find a list of releases of the gradle plugin here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: What if your not using gradle?

Comment: @J.M.: I have no way to answer that, sorry.

Comment: Also be careful where you put the <queries>, if you accidentally nest them under <application> in your manifest, you'll see a similar-looking error

Answer (score 102):

I had this issue in Flutter, but I believe this solution will work for both Flutter and native Flutter development.

Follow these steps

1. Read this short blog post to get some understanding: *[Preparing your Gradle build for package visibility in Android 11](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/preparing-your-build-for-package-visibility-in-android-11.html)*
2. Delete the *.gradle* folder inside the Android folder, i.e., android > .gradle
3. In the project *build.gradle* file, upgrade your class path appropriately based on the blog in the link above, e.g., I upgraded to  `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'`
4. Upgrade the distribution URL too. It's in android>gradle>gradle-wrapper.properties file appropriately. E.g., I upgraded it to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip`
5. You can invalidate caches and restart your Android Studio. Make sure you have a good Internet connection, because it will download the new [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) files.

Comment: This works in react native too, very useful

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.2-all.zip
I still get issue how to fix?

Comment: Did you invalidate caches after the updates?

Comment: getting dexGuard issue with this:  supported versions include [2.3.0:3.5.*]

Answer (score 84):

I also suddenly had the same issue two days ago in Android Studio 4.1.1. I solved the issue by upgrading the build Gradle version.

Previous setting in the *build.gradle* file of the project was:

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
```

Current setting:

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4")
```

The issue was gone immediately. :)

Comment: I solved the problem with your answer. I have Android Studio 4.2.1  Thanks!

Comment: Can confirm this works for Android Studio 4.2.1 and Flutter 2 (I migrated from 1.22.6)

Comment: best solution ever :)

Comment: Having problem with flutter camera plugin recently, this solution worked like flawlessly. Thank you.

Comment: I faced the same problem in React Native with react-native-inappbrowser-reborn. This solution solved my problem

Answer (score 76):

Update your Android Studio to the last version
and use the last stable [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) plugin version.
At the current time, I use **Android Studio** version **4.1.3** with **Gradle Plugin 6.8.2**

For use in *queries*, you should write *queries* code in out of *application* tag, not inside **application** tag.

For more information, see the photo below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks0AY.jpg]

Comment: VERY IMPORTANT **guys please attentions, for use queries you should write queries code in out of application tag not inside application tag**

Comment: Could have used full photo, wheres other application tag

Comment: I have the same issue. But mine is the manifest file from jetified-billing-6.2.0. How to fix this?

Answer (score 16):

I had this error in the `react-native-image-crop-picker` library, and I solved this problem by updating the Gradle version as mentioned in previous answers.

It was:

```java
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
```

Updated to:

```java
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4")
```

And I ran a:

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && npx react-native run-android
```

Then it worked OK.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the new default settings and features for **package visibility** in [Android 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_11) that need to add `<queries>`, you must update your Android [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) plugin.

Google has added some patches to current versions listed in *[Android Gradle plugin release notes, 4.0.0 (April 2020)](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html?buildsystem=cmake#4-0-0)*.

If you want to use a newer version of Android Gradle, you should search for a compatible wrapper from *[Android Gradle plugin release notes, Update Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html?buildsystem=cmake#updating-gradle)*.

Answer (score 1):

As of AGP 8.x, when getting the warning:

```
Unknown element under <manifest>: queries at /data/app/***/base.apk Binary XML file line #11
```

This happens when running eg. on Android 10. It's not the manifest-merger, which doesn't know the element, but it is the manifest-parser on the device. The property `tools:targetApi="R"` sadly is not being baked into the merged manifest. Unless creating a modern and legacy build-type with two different manifests, the best one can do is to ignore the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Gradle version to 4.0.1 or later.

File *android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties*: update the distribution URL to:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip

File *android/build.gradle*: update the [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) plugin:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'

to 4.0.1 or later. Here it is 4.1.2 with Gradle version to 6.5 or later.

You can see the distribution chart at *[How to update gradle in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio/35272475#35272475)*