# Flutter : PlatformException(no_available_camera, No cameras available for taking pictures., null, null)

Tags: flutter, android-camera, android-permissions, imagepicker

guys! I am facing this camera version. It happened after I merged my projects. It says there is no camera available but back then it was running fine. Please have a look!

```
E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(no_available_camera, No cameras available for taking pictures., null, null)
    #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:582:7)
    #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159:18)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:12)
    #3      MethodChannelImagePicker.pickImagePath (package:image_picker_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_image_picker.dart:62:21)
    #4      MethodChannelImagePicker.pickImage (package:image_picker_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_image_picker.dart:30:25)
    #5      ImagePicker.getImage (package:image_picker/image_picker.dart:101:21)
    #6      _ImageEvaluationState.getImage (package:PhotoEarn/screens/camera/image_evaluation.dart:201:38)
    #7      _ImageEvaluationState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:PhotoEarn/screens/camera/image_evaluation.dart:1099:33)
    #8      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:993:19)
    #9      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1111:38)
    #10     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:183:24)
    #11     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:598:11)
    #12     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:287:5)
    #13     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:259:7)
    #14     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:157:27)
    #15     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:362:20)
    #16     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:22)
    #17     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:267:11)
    #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295:7)
    #19     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:240:7)
    #20     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:213:7)
    #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
    #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
    #23     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
    #24     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:265:10)
    #25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:174:5)
```

Please have a look at this error message and help in this. I am looking to hearing from you all. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess the issue was fixed in flutter's master branch, try switching to master and try again

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` is 30 (or above), then add the queries info to your Android manifest file, directly under the manifest tag:

```
<manifest package="your.app.package.name">
    <queries>
          <intent>
               <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
          </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

That should resolve your issue.

Comment: in which folder??

Comment: In android/app/src/main the manifest is usually located.

Comment: Just as a FYI for those new to manual editing the manifest,  <uses-permission> tag goes directly under the <manifest>

Answer (score 27):

I'm not sure adding `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` is the correct solution given the goal is to access the camera only. If `targetSdkVersion=30` (or higher), adding `<queries>` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` looks to be a preferable solution as per here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63246789/268156

```
<manifest package="com.example">
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: This is by far the best and the most safe solution. It works perfectly. I don't know why it wasn't accepted but it really is much better than QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES which can also be forbidden by google

Answer (score 7):

I face same issue. For android, you need to add Camera permission and Query all packages permission in AndroidManifest.xml file as below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting android 11/ android sdk 30 or above, you need to add the following permission to android manifest xml file.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>`

It may throw another warning, but you can just ignore it for the time being. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I was testing on `Emulator`, when I switched to `Real device`, everything was working fine.

Comment: Same for me. Which is weird. we have to still be able to test it in simulator/emulator. Even if it's just a simple click just to show it works.