# Not able to Open Camera from emulator in Android 30 in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, camera, android-emulator, imagepicker

> I am using image picker to capture image and was testing on emulator
> with SDK 30. I is always throwing exception no camera available and is
> working perfectly in real device.

**manifest file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.abc">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your code snippet.

Comment: Thanks @TusharPatel for your help.

Comment: [If your compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion is 30 (or above), then add the queries info to your Android manifest file, directly under the manifest tag:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64693774/16766799)