# queryIntentActivities returning empty list in android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-11

I am trying to open Gmail from my app ( on click of button) . I am facing issue in android 11 only . Its not opening the Gmail . queryIntentActivities is returning empty list in this case.

Please help me how to fix this issue for android 11.
Below is the code which i am using ..

```
 val pkgManager = aContext.packageManager
            val packages = pkgManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)
            if (!packages.isEmpty()) {
                for (resolveInfo in packages) {
                    val packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName
                    aEmailClientNames.add(resolveInfo.loadLabel(aContext.packageManager).toString())
                    aEmailClientIcons.add(resolveInfo.loadIcon(aContext.packageManager))
                    aEmailClientPackageNames.add(packageName)
                }
```

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63246442/android-11-r-return-empty-list-when-querying-intent-for-action-image-capture)?

Comment: Yes i checked that one. That is for opening image . They are adding query in manifest file.  what query to add in manifest to open gmail app? i tried many but didnt get result.

Comment: its working after adding permission  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>

Comment: "what query to add in manifest to open gmail app?" -- you need one that matches whatever you are specifying in `intent` in the second line of your code snippet. "its working after adding permission" -- bear in mind that you may be banned from the Play Store, unless you can provide justification to Google for why you need this permission.

Answer (score 21):

> `packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)` will return EMPTY list if your app is running on **`targetSdkVersion 30`** to resolved this issue you have to use `<queries>` in menifest as **`queryIntentActivities()`**, are filtered based on the calling app's  declaration.

**Fix image capture + image upload to work with Android "scoped storage"**

The issue can be related to new package visibility (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility).
After all updates (at least Android Studio 4.1) try to add in your manifest  that shows what action is required in app.
In my case problem disappears when adds.

**IMAGE_CAPTURE** for CAMERA, **GET_CONTENT** for GALLERY (to get files change mimeType if you want video), **PICK** for GALLERY (should change mimetype if u want video)
**CHOOSER** for GALLERY (if someone have other image browsers)

You can also check in logcat what queries you have to add (should contains "BLOCKED" or "no permission".
Error is because `ImagePickerModule` when you don't have permission in Intent with `resolveActivity` returns `null` (you can comment it to check better errors in `startActivityForResult`)

**Add `<query>` in `AndroidMenifest.xml`**

```
<manifest>
.....
.....
<queries>
    <!-- Browser -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
    </intent>
    <!-- Camera -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
    <!-- Gallery -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER" />
     </intent>

     <!--For external application-->
     <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
</queries>
.....
.....
</manifest>
```

Comment: I had the same issue. The solution you provided helped me a bit, but still, I don't get all the Apps that are usually available for sharing (like WhatsApp, Facebook etc.) What is missing?

Comment: I just realized that the newly added permission `android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` was missing in the manifest. So, adding additionally this line solved my problem:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />`

Comment: @MehmedMert you can also add the particular package under the `<queries>`  to resolve the issue for example for Whatsapp you can add `<package android:name="com.whatsapp" />`

Please check my updated answer for batter idea

Comment: perfect answer <3

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
```

Don't forget to paste this line of code in manifest

Comment: You can't publish regular app to GooglePlay with this permission https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779?hl=en