# How to add queries declaration in the manifest for using camera

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-camera-intent

```
private fun clickPhoto(){
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
            takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(requireActivity().packageManager)?.also {
                val photoFile: File? = try {
                    createFile(requireActivity(), Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, "jpg")
                } catch (ex: IOException) {
                    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), getString(R.string.create_file_Error, ex.message),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    null
                }
                photoFile?.also {
                    selectedPhotoPath = it.absolutePath
                    val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        requireActivity(),
                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider",
                        it
                    )
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_PHOTO_REQUEST)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my click photo function where resolveActivity() gives a warning `Consider adding a <queries> declaration to your manifest when calling this method; see https://g.co/dev/packagevisibility for details`.I know that since API 30 we need queries to access the information of other installed apps.

I also know that this can be resolved by not using resolveActivity() but i want to learn how to add queries to manifest.

This is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.akaalistudios.employeemanagement">

    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.EmployeeManagement">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You could simply remove the `resolveActivity()` call. Instead, wrap your `startActivityForResult()` call in a `try`/`catch` block.

Answer (score -1):

In order to access a broader list of installed apps, an app can specify information about apps they need to query and interact with directly. This can be done by adding a  element in the Android manifest.

For most common scenarios, including any implicit intents started with startActivity(), you won’t have to change anything! For other scenarios, like opening a specific third party application directly from your UI, developers will have to explicitly list the application package names or intent filter signatures like this:

```
<manifest package="com.example.game">
  <queries>
    <!-- Specific apps you interact with, eg: -->
    <package android:name="com.example.store" />
    <package android:name="com.example.service" />
    <!--
         Specific intents you query for,
         eg: for a custom share UI
    -->
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
      <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
    </intent>
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```

For more details you must have to follow these links :
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9
or
[Android 11 (R) return empty list when querying intent for ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63246442/android-11-r-return-empty-list-when-querying-intent-for-action-image-capture)

I hope it might help.