# A problem occurred evaluating project ':firebase_auth'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

this error doesn't occur when project is already running state. but next day i tried to run the same project then this error apears.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'D:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-3.2.0\android\build.gradle'
>   line: 58
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':firebase_auth'.
>
> > Could not load compiled classes for script 'D:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-3.2.0\android\user-agent.gradle'
> > from cache.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 17s
>
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 Exited
> (sigterm)

this are my pubspec.yml dependencies

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: "^1.10.0"
  firebase_auth: ^3.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an **android configuration** problem.

The solution is to add the **dependencies** to your android project.

The first step is to follow the instructions on Firebase Auth's pub.dev page

You can do this by adding the following lines to your *android/build.gradle* file:

```
dependencies {
    // Example existing classpath
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
   // Add the google services classpath
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
 }
```

and adding the following line to the bottom of your *android/app/build.gradle* file

```
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The next thing to do is add the Firebase Auth plugin to your **android implementations**

To do this you should follow the instructions  => https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries

Cheers ! :-)

Comment: no, not working.. ur above steps are already included in my configuration

Comment: flutter clean then pub get then check

Comment: also read this ====> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64932702/flutter-failure-build-failed-with-an-exception/64932927

Comment: flutter clean then flutter pub get doesn't work. now trying ur second suggestion.

Comment: also not worked... whenever i removed dependecy of firebase auth .. then it gets run.. problem with firebase auth

Comment: Maybe issue with config

Comment: may be, i have to flush flutter and reinstall flutter.