# Unexpected error when updating Flutter_inappwebview

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

[image: xml]Does anyone understand why I am getting this error after updating the Flutter_inappwebview package?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `AndroidManifest.xml`, the error says "unexpected element . It's probably not insterted in the proper place or proper format. Fix that and post your xml file please.

Also see this, it has your current situation:
[How to fix "unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969917/how-to-fix-unexpected-element-queries-found-in-manifest-error)

Comment: I tried removing it but it puts it back on the code when I start runing the app @HuthaifaMuayyad

Comment: Did you check the link?

Comment: thank you I figure out how to update the gradle pluging with your link