# Using flutter google_mobile_ads package result in error

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, google-mobile-ads

In my flutter app I am trying to implement ads with the google_mobile_ads package. My app is completely working till I add the package in the pubspec.yml file. After adding the package and changing the AndroidManifest.xml file (currently using the Sample AdMob app ID):

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
```

I get following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  > Android resource linking failed
    C:\Users\<user>\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\4b972deff280dc86e6977f77fe6522be\play-services-ads-lite-20.4.0\AndroidManifest.xml:28:5-44:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 30s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             31,9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Regarding to another question on Stack Overflow ([How to fix "unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969917/how-to-fix-unexpected-element-queries-found-in-manifest-error)) I updated the classpath in build.gradle file to `classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4")`

To fixed the upcoming error (`Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin`)
I also upgraded the kotlin version to 1.6.10.

Because this step resulted in `The current Gradle version 5.6.2 is not compatible with the Kotlin Gradle plugin. Please use Gradle 6.1.1 or newer` I also updated the distributionUrl to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6.1-all.zip`

After all this fixes the flutter run command will run in a loop and the only thing I see on my virtual device is the error message that my app has stopped. ([Error on virtual device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csAsb.jpg))

It doesn´t make a differance if I add `MobileAds.instance.initialize();`to my code or not. I always get the errors above.

What I already tried:

- Various verions of google_mobile_ads, gradle kotlin and distributionUrl
- Creating a new flutter project
- On a real device

Flutter Doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1415], locale de-DE)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.7.4)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[√] Connected device (5 available)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I started my app on a real device again i stumbled across a message that the google_mobile_ads packages isn´t set up correctly. I found out that I added the meta data in the manifest.xml file at the wrong place. See the code below to get the right place:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.remote">
<application>
    <activity>
        <meta-data/>
        <meta-data>
            **Where I added it**
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"
        <meta-data/>
        <intent-filter/>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        **Where it has to be added** 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />
    <meta-data/>
</application>
<uses-permission/>
</manifest>
```